# How do you check if value exists and then either add or update values in firebase with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have an app where users can log in and add trips they've been on. my fb db structure is like so

```
{
  "users": {
    "randomId": {
      "Place1": {
        "name": "Place1",
        "somedata": "oianoiasnfianafs",
        "moredata": "asdasdadasdas",
        "THISKEYIWANTTOUPDATE": [
          {
            "data": "asasfas"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can see the key above I want to update. but my problem is, I first need to check if Place1 already exists in the database? how do I achieve this? I know I could call `set` but not sure if this is the best thing to do? I'm also aware of update but I want logic like this pseudo code below

```
if (place1) {
 // call update()
} else {
 // cat set()
}
```

I'm not sure how to do the `if(place1)` part though? and if it's best practice in firebase to check if it exists?

Comment: Is that `"Place1"` alway the only attribute or the first attribute of  `"randomId"` ?

Comment: there could be multiple places. sorry I should have said. there may be another key called "Place2"

Comment: Is it possible that `randomId` have only `"place2"`, but no `"place1"` ? Is it possible, how do you deal it ? set `"place2"`  to `place1"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `Object.keys(obj)` to get attribute of object.

assume that userObj is

```
   "users": {
      "randomId": {
        "Place1": {
            "name": "Place1",
            "somedata": "oianoiasnfianafs",
            "moredata": "asdasdadasdas",
            "THISKEYIWANTTOUPDATE": [
                {
                    "data": "asasfas"
                },
            ]
        },
      }
   }
```

and you have mentioned that it could be mulitple `PlaceN` under `randomID`, then I suggest that the pattern might be :

multiple case, have `Place2` and value of `Place1` is null:

```
      "randomId": {
        "Place1": {
         },    
         "Place2": {
            "name": "Place2",
            "somedata": "oianoiasnfianafs",
            "moredata": "asdasdadasdas",
            "THISKEYIWANTTOUPDATE": [
                {
                    "data": "asasfas"
                },
            ]
         }, 

       }
```

and the check function:

```
checkPlace1ExistOrNot=(userObj)=>{
    let tempRandomId = userObj[Object.keys(userObj)[0]]  //It should be vale of "RandomId"
    if(tempRandomId[Object.keys(tempRandomId)[0]])
    {
        return true     // users.randomId.Place1 is exist
    }
    else
    {
        return false    // users.randomId.Place1 is not exist
    }
}
```